# Exoplayer to play live video chunks received as byte arrays one after another maintaining continuity

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to develop a live video streaming application using bluetooth.

I already have completed up to receiving video chunks in the client side where a callback gets called when each video chunk arrives, like the one given below.

```
    chunkReceived(Byte[] chunk)
    {

    }
```

Now I have to develop a video player using Exoplayer which goes on playing the video chunks as they are received. I had a look into the Exoplayer documentation but it mostly deals with playing from a URI and there is not enough explanation on how to play video chunks one after another maintaining continuity.

Can any one please help me on this or share your ideas on this.

Comment: Can you share a solution if the issue has been resolved? I am having the same problem and I am struggling with understanding how to implement custom DataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom sources, com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DataSource interface has to be implemented.

In the callback you mentioned, store the data and in the read function of new datasource, provide the stored data.

For supporting RTP in exoplayer for a previous project, I did the same and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! Is a custom SampleSource too required?

Comment: What is the media format? If it is supported container like mpegts, then available sample source can be used.

Comment: It is mp4 and is available in ExtractorSampleSource. I tried this and it seems that the received data is corrupted and the playback fails. Did you faced something similar?

Comment: would it be possibel for you to share your custom datasource class ? i am facing the issue where exoplayer doesn't read properly.